# How does Google Maps calculate walking time?

Tags: google-maps

[image: screen shot from Google Maps showing walking route]

In above linked image, Google Maps is showing that a distance of 293km can be covered by walking in 2 days and 12 hours. Does this estimated time include rest/sleep time or is it continuous uninterrupted walking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is **continuous walking without interruption**.

---

#### Reasoning

2 days and 12hrs is 60hrs.

```
293km/60hrs ≃ 300km/60hrs = 5km/h
```

> the average human walking speed at crosswalks is about 5.0 kilometres per hour (km/h)

[Source wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walking)

Comment: However (google maps shows) time is reduced if going downslope.